# Modify a button when another one is clicked

Tags: android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a ListView with multiple items.
I want the user to be able to vote or downvote items.

***When the user clicks the "upvote" button it should turn green, and the "downvote" button should go back to normal (or remain unchanged).***

Same principle applies when user click "downvote" button.

From now on I've tried this code

```
holder.buttonUpvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageButton buttonUpvote = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpvote);
    ImageButton buttonDownvote = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonDownvote);

    buttonUpvote.setBackgroundColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.upvoteColor));
    buttonDownvote.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "voted UP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

  }
});

holder.buttonDownvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageButton buttonUpvote = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpvote);
    ImageButton buttonDownvote = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonDownvote);

    buttonUpvote.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    buttonDownvote.setBackgroundColor(v.getResources().getColor(R.color.downvoteColor));

    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "voted DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  }
});
```

I get a beautiful null pointer (and I deserve it) since "v" is the button itself...
I don't see how I can get out of this...

The layout is just 2 buttons in a relative layout.

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should have just initialized the buttons out of the onClickListener. Then you don't need the parent view.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Yes it also works, and it has the benefit to avoid duplicate calls since the buttons are the same in each listener. It also allows me to change the layout without bothering the class of the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onClick` `v` parameter is instance of clicked View which is `ImageView` so no need to call `findViewById` to access it.

Use `v.getParent()` to access Buttons if both parent is same:

```
View parent = (View)v.getParent();
ImageButton buttonUpvote = (ImageButton) parent.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpvote);
 ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, it solved the problem perfectly.